# When a permanent magnet is quantum locked above a superconductor and is spinning what variables/calculations dictate how fast it spins?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconduction

Basically, I want to know whether it’s the size of the permanent magnet, a.k.a. the strength of the permanent magnets, magnetic field, or the super conductor that decides how fast it will spin whether it’s going to spin faster or slower. Currently observed a super conductor that caused a permanent magnet to quantum lock and spin at 54 RPM. Can these be predicted or is it more of experiment and find out only? What’s the math?

Comment: Theoretical models are all someone's imagination until you have something real to back it.  I say it's affected by everything you mention and everything else.

Comment: @abel was not a theoretical model. The observed affect was experimental a real super conductor with a real permanent magnet.

Comment: Sentence about theoretical models pertains to: "is it more of experiment and find out only?" - anything of relevance to reality will always require "experiment and find out" One about affects pertains to "whether it’s the... or the... that decides..." - never a matter of whether; just how much.